# swiper js problem with breakpoints in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, breakpoints, swiper.js

I have two Swiperjs sliders in my homepage. before using breakpoints for making these sliders responsive, there were no problems with sliders, but after i used breakpoints, there are different malfunctioning in these two sliders as below:

1- in first slider, when i resize the browser window from 992px breakpoint to 1168px breakponit (last breakpoint), it shows some empthy slides after going forward some slides.

2-in second slider, when I resize the browser window from any breakpoint to 992px breakponit (last breakpoint) by clicking window Maximize button, instead of showing expected slides per view, it shows one slide with abnormally big size.

my slider component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Navigation, Pagination } from "swiper";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Thumbs } from "swiper";

import CrossBike from "../../assets/images/Cross-Bike.jpg";
import CityBike from "../../assets/images/City-Bike.jpg";
import MountainBike from "../../assets/images/Mountain-bike.jpg";
import RoadBike from "../../assets/images/Road-bike.jpg";

import "./Carousel.css";

// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "swiper/css/scrollbar";

function Carousel(props) {
  const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Swiper
        style={props.style}
        className={props.class}
        // install Swiper modules
        modules={[Thumbs, Navigation]}
        thumbs={{
          swiper: thumbsSwiper && !thumbsSwiper.destroyed ? thumbsSwiper : null,
        }}
        loop={true}
        // Responsive breakpoints

        breakpoints={props.responsive && props.breakpoints}
        spaceBetween={props.space}
        slidesPerView={props.spv}
        navigation
        onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
        onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
      >
        {props.children}
      </Swiper>

      {props.thumb ? (
        <Swiper
          modules={[Thumbs]}
          watchSlidesProgress
          onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
          slidesPerView={4}
          spaceBetween={20}
          height={100}
          className="thumbs"
        >
          <SwiperSlide>
            <img className="Image" src={CrossBike} />
          </SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide>
            <img className="Image" src={CityBike} />
          </SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide>
            <img className="Image" src={MountainBike} />
          </SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide>
            <img className="Image" src={RoadBike} />
          </SwiperSlide>
        </Swiper>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Carousel;
```

my first slider

```
<Carousel
            class="big-card-carousel"
            responsive
            breakpoints={{
              // when window width is >= 480px
              480: {
                slidesPerView: 1,
                //spaceBetween: 40,
              },
              // when window width is >= 640px
              768: {
                slidesPerView: 3,
                //spaceBetween: 100,
              },
              992: {
                slidesPerView: 4,
                // spaceBetween: 40,
              },
              1168: {
                slidesPerView: 1,
                // spaceBetween: 40,
              },
            }}
          >
            <SwiperSlide>
              <div className="big-card-wrapper">
                <ProductCart
                  image={img}
                  class="big-card"
                  price=" €39.99"
                  title=" Endura Hummvee Cycling Trousers II"
                />
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <div className="big-card-wrapper">
                <ProductCart
                  image={img}
                  class="big-card"
                  price=" €39.99"
                  title=" Endura Hummvee Cycling Trousers II"
                />
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <div className="big-card-wrapper">
                <ProductCart
                  image={img}
                  class="big-card"
                  price=" €39.99"
                  title=" Endura Hummvee Cycling Trousers II"
                />
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <div className="big-card-wrapper">
                <ProductCart
                  image={img}
                  class="big-card"
                  price=" €39.99"
                  title=" Endura Hummvee Cycling Trousers II"
                />
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
          </Carousel>
```

my second slider:

```
<Carousel
        style={{ height: "464px" }}
        responsive
        breakpoints={{
          // when window width is >= 480px
          480: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            //spaceBetween: 40,
          },
          // when window width is >= 640px
          768: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            //spaceBetween: 100,
          },
          992: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            // spaceBetween: 40,
          },
        }}
      >
        <SwiperSlide>
          <ProductCart
            image={img}
            price=" €39.99"
            title=" Endura Hummvee Cycling Trousers II"
          />
        </SwiperSlide>

        <SwiperSlide>
          <ProductCart
            image={img}
            price=" €39.99"
            title=" Endura Hummvee Cycling Trousers II"
          />
        </SwiperSlide>

        <SwiperSlide>
          <ProductCart
            image={img}
            price=" €39.99"
            title=" Endura Hummvee Cycling Trousers II"
          />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <ProductCart
            image={img}
            price=" €39.99"
            title=" Endura Hummvee Cycling Trousers II"
          />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <ProductCart
            image={img}
            price=" €39.99"
            title=" Endura Hummvee Cycling Trousers II"
          />
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Carousel>
    );
```

video of first slider:
[first slider](https://youtu.be/SJmTS2qWQ1o)

video of second slider:
[second slider](https://youtu.be/y22zJyU0oJ8)

i tried changing breakpoints and manipulating css classes but nothing changed.

Comment: can you please edit this line inside your Carousel component in Swiper element `breakpoints={props.breakpoints}`

Comment: @AousMohammad it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be fixed by removing the loop property